# Resolving i18n and field error in test case vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

```
<template>
  <v-dialog
    v-model="dialog"
    persistent
    :fullscreen="isMobile"
    max-width="755"
    style="z-index: 9999"
  >
    <v-card :class="isMobile ? 'rounded-0' : 'rounded-lg'" elevation="0" class="bg-white" flat>
      <template #prepend>
        <div>
          <v-chip
            class="font-weight-600"
            :color="!submitFeedback ? 'yellow-lighten-2' : 'success'"
            :style="{ background: !submitFeedback ? 'yellow-lighten-1' : 'green-lighten-1' }"
            label
          >
            <label class="text-uppercase">
              {{ !submitFeedback ? BookingStatus.FeedbackDue : BookingStatus.Done }}
            </label>
          </v-chip>
        </div>
      </template>
      <template #append>
        <v-avatar size="23" class="rounded-0">
          <v-img :src="Cross" @click="close()"></v-img>
        </v-avatar>
      </template>
      <v-card-item class="py-7">
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12" md="6">
            <div class="font-weight-600 title-3">️ {{ getDateFormat }}</div>
            <div class="mt-5 d-flex align-center">
              <v-icon icon="mdi-clock-time-four-outline mr-2" />
              <label class="mr-4 font-weight-600 text-subtitle-1">
                {{ getStartTime }}
                <v-icon size="small" icon="mdi-arrow-right-thin" />
                {{ getEndTime }}
              </label>
              <v-chip>
                {{ setDialogData?.location }}
              </v-chip>
            </div>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" md="6" class="d-flex align-center">
            <div class="d-flex align-center">
              <v-avatar size="60" class="mr-5">
                <v-img :src="setDialogData?.expert_photo || DefaultCompany" />
              </v-avatar>
              <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                <div>
                  <h6 class="title-3 font-weight-600">
                    {{ setDialogData?.expert_name }}
                  </h6>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <p class="">
                    with
                    <v-avatar size="20" class="ml-3">
                      <v-img :src="setDialogData?.incubee_photo || DefaultCompany" />
                    </v-avatar>
                    {{ setDialogData?.incubee_name }}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-card-item>

      <!-- progress bar -->
      <div class="d-flex justify-center flex-column pa-8 bg-background">
        <p
          v-if="!isMobileComputed"
          class="title-5 text-md-center text-primary font-weight-600 text-center"
        >
          {{ currentStep }}/{{ totalSteps }}
        </p>
        <v-progress-linear
          :model-value="progressBarValue"
          class="text-md-center w-50 mb-8"
          color="primary"
        >
        </v-progress-linear>

        <!-- <v-card-text> -->
        <!-- stepper render -->
        <div class="form-container">
          <div v-for="(stepinput, index) in feedbackSteps" :key="stepinput.step">
            <div v-show="stepinput.step == currentStep" :class="stepinput.class">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-space-between ga-6 mb-2 position-relative">
                <p class="font-weight-500 w-75 question-class">{{ stepinput.question }}</p>
                <v-avatar size="20" class="mt-1 rounded-0 pointer">
                  <v-img :src="QuestionMarkIcon" />
                </v-avatar>
              </div>
              <v-row
                v-if="stepinput.step === 1 || stepinput.step === 2 || stepinput.step === 3"
                class="position-absolute mt-0"
              >
                <v-col>
                  <v-chip
                    :color="stepinput.chipColor"
                    :class="stepinput.chipclass"
                    class="font-weight-600"
                    size="small"
                    label
                  >
                    {{ stepinput.tag }}
                  </v-chip>
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
              <p class="custom-text" v-if="stepinput.step === 4 || stepinput.step === 5">
                {{ stepinput.tag }}
              </p>
              <vee-form
                :validation-schema="stepinput.validations"
                as="form"
                :id="`myForm-${stepinput.step}`"
                @submit="submitOrNext"
              >
                <vee-field :name="stepinput.name" v-slot="{ field, errors }">
                  <component
                    v-model="formData[stepinput.name]"
                    :is="stepinput.component"
                    :key="`${stepinput.name}-${index}`"
                    :error-messages="errors"
                    :errors="errors"
                    :tags="stepinput.tags"
                    v-bind="dynamicProps(stepinput, field)"
                  />
                </vee-field>
              </vee-form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div
        class="d-flex justify-space-between pa-8"
        :class="isMobileComputed ? 'bottom-navigation-container' : 'bg-background'"
      >
        <div
          v-if="currentStep === 1"
          :class="isMobileComputed && 'initial-text'"
          class="align-self-center align-items-center d-flex ga-3"
        >
          <p class="text-subtitle-1 font-weight-400">
            {{ $t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.LBL") }}
          </p>
          <v-chip
            class="font-weight-600 cursor-pointer click-btn-class"
            color="primary"
            variant="outlined"
            size="large"
          >
            {{ $t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.BTN_TXT") }}
          </v-chip>
        </div>

        <span
          v-if="currentStep > 1 && isMobileComputed"
          class="previous-btn-responsive"
          @click="previous"
        >
          {{ $t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.PREVIOUS_TXT") }}</span
        >
        <v-btn
          v-if="currentStep > 1 && !isMobileComputed"
          class="text-primary rounded-lg"
          size="x-large"
          variant="outlined"
          color="primary"
          @click="previous"
        >
          {{ $t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.PREVIOUS_QUESTION_TXT") }}
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn
          class="bg-primary rounded-lg"
          size="x-large"
          type="submit"
          :form="`myForm-${currentStep}`"
        >
          {{
            currentStep < 5
              ? isMobileComputed
                ? $t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.NEXT_TXT")
                : $t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.NEXT_QUESTION_TXT")
              : $t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.BTN_TXT")
          }}
        </v-btn>
      </div>
      <!-- </v-card-text> -->
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
  <base-feedback-dialog :rateDialog="rateDialog" :setDialogData="setDialogData" />
</template>



<script setup lang="ts">
import { useUiStore } from "@/store/UiStore";
import { toRef } from "vue";
import { watchEffect } from "vue";
import { ref } from "vue";
import { BookingStatus, IncubeeBookedOfficeHours } from "@/models/office-hours.model";
import Cross from "@assets/icons/cross.svg";
import { Ref } from "vue";
import { computed } from "vue";
import { Clock } from "@/utils/clock";
import { inject } from "vue";
import { clockKey } from "@/plugins/clock";
import DefaultCompany from "@assets/default_profile.jpg";
import QuestionMarkIcon from "../../assets/icons/circled-question.svg";
import { useOfficeHoursStore } from "@/store/OfficeHoursStore";
import { watch } from "vue";
import BaseRating from "@components/base/BaseRating.vue";
import BaseAmmenities from "@components/base/BaseAmmenities.vue";
import BaseFeedbackTag from "@components/base/BaseFeedbackTag.vue";
import i18n from "@/plugins/i18n";
import * as yup from "yup";

const emits = defineEmits();
const props = defineProps({
  openDialog: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  setDialogData: {
    type: Object,
    default: {} as IncubeeBookedOfficeHours,
  },
});

const dialog = ref(false);
const rateDialog = ref(false);
const openDialog = toRef(props, "openDialog");
const setDialogData = toRef(props, "setDialogData") as Ref<IncubeeBookedOfficeHours>;
const uiStore = useUiStore();
const ohStore = useOfficeHoursStore();
const isMobile = uiStore.isMobileViewEnabled;
const submitFeedback = ref(ohStore.getSubmitFeedback);
const clock = inject(clockKey) as Clock;

const formData = ref<any>({});

const tags = [
  {
    value: 0,
    icon: "thumbup",
    iconType: "basesvg",
    text: i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.THUMB_UP_TXT"),
  },
  {
    value: 1,
    icon: "thumbdown",
    iconType: "basesvg",
    text: i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.THUMB_DOWN_TXT"),
  },
];

const isMobileComputed = computed(() => {
  return uiStore.isMobileViewEnabled;
});

const feedbackSteps = ref([
  {
    step: 1,
    component: BaseRating,
    name: "feedback_rating",
    label: "Share your rating",
    class: "",
    chipclass: "",
    chipColor: "#929BAE",
    validations: yup.object({
      feedback_rating: yup
        .string()
        .trim()
        .required(i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.STEPS.STEP_ONE.VALIDATION")),
    }),
    question: i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.STEPS.STEP_ONE.QUESTION"),
    tag: i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.STEPS.STEP_ONE.TAG"),
  },
  {
    step: 2,
    component: "v-textarea",
    name: "feedback_message_incubee",
    validations: yup.object({
      feedback_message_incubee: yup
        .string()
        .trim()
        .required(i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.STEPS.STEP_TWO.VALIDATION")),
    }),
    class: "custom-textarea-container",
    chipclass: "custom-chip",
    chipColor: "red",
    props: {
      variant: "outlined",
      "auto-grow": true,
      placeholder: "Please type here",
      color: "background",
    },
    question: i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.STEPS.STEP_TWO.QUESTION"),
    tag: i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.STEPS.STEP_TWO.TAG"),
  },
  {
    step: 3,
    component: "v-textarea",
    name: "feedback_message_staff",
    validations: yup.object({
      feedback_message_staff: yup
        .string()
        .trim()
        .required(i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.STEPS.STEP_THIRD.VALIDATION")),
    }),
    class: "custom-textarea-container",
    chipclass: "custom-chip",
    chipColor: "#2F86DF",
    props: {
      variant: "outlined",
      "auto-grow": true,
      placeholder: i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.STEPS.STEP_THIRD.PLACEHOLDER"),
      color: "background",
    },
    question: i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.STEPS.STEP_THIRD.QUESTION"),
    tag: i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.STEPS.STEP_THIRD.TAG"),
  },
  {
    step: 4,
    component: BaseAmmenities,
    name: "ammenities",
    question: i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.STEPS.STEP_FOUR.QUESTION"),
    tag: i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.STEPS.STEP_FOUR.TAG"),
    validations: yup.object({
      ammenities: yup
        .array()
        .min(1, i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.STEPS.STEP_FOUR.VALIDATION"))
        .required(i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.STEPS.STEP_FOUR.VALIDATION_TWO")),
    }),
    props: {
      options: [
        { text: "Preparedness", value: "Preparedness" },
        { text: "Punctuality", value: "Punctuality" },
        { text: "Responsiveness", value: "Responsiveness" },
        { text: "Relevance", value: "Relevance" },
        { text: "Politeness/Courtesy", value: "Politeness/Courtesy" },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    step: 5,
    component: BaseFeedbackTag,
    name: "feedback_message_answer",
    validations: yup.object({
      feedback_message_answer: yup
        .number()
        .required(i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.EXPERT_MOBILE_VALIDATE.REQUIRED")),
    }),
    question: i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.STEPS.STEP_FIVE.QUESTION"),
    tags: tags,
    props: {
      textAlign: "center",
    },
  },
]);

const currentStep = ref(1);
const totalSteps = feedbackSteps.value.length;

const progressBarValue = computed(() => {
  return (currentStep.value / totalSteps) * 100;
});

const previous = () => {
  if (currentStep.value > 1) {
    currentStep.value--;
  }
};
const submitOrNext = () => {
  if (currentStep.value === totalSteps) {
    submitForm();
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

const next = () => {
  if (currentStep.value < totalSteps) {
    currentStep.value++;
  }
};

const clearAll = () => {
  formData.value = {};
  currentStep.value = 1;
};

const submitForm = () => {
  clearAll();
  close();
  uiStore.showSnackbar(i18n.global.t("GLOBAL_COMPONENTS.FEEDBACK.FEEDBACK_SNACKBAR_SUCCESS_MSG"));
};

watchEffect(() => {
  dialog.value = openDialog.value;
});

watch(
  () => ohStore.getSubmitFeedback,
  (newSubmitFeedback) => {
    submitFeedback.value = newSubmitFeedback;
  },
);

const getDateFormat = computed(
  () => !!clock && clock.parse(setDialogData.value.start_hour).toDateComplete(),
);
const getStartTime = computed(
  () => !!clock && clock.parse(setDialogData.value.start_hour).toTime(),
);
const getEndTime = computed(() => !!clock && clock.parse(setDialogData.value.end_hour).toTime());

const close = () => {
  dialog.value = !openDialog.value;
  emits("closeFeedbackDialolg");
};

const dynamicProps = (stepinput: any, field: any) => {
  const commonProps = {
    ...field,
    class: "mt-8",
  };

  if (stepinput.props) {
    return { ...commonProps, ...stepinput.props };
  }

  return commonProps;
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.form-container {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.question-class {
  font-size: 19px;
}

.bottom-navigation-container {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}

.initial-text {
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.click-btn-class {
  width: 105px;
}

.custom-textarea-container {
  position: relative;
}

.custom-chip {
  left: 16px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.custom-textarea {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  background-color: white !important;
}

.custom-textarea .v-textarea__slot {
  padding-top: 24px;
  border: none;
}

.custom-textarea label {
  display: none;
}
.custom-text {
  color: var(--Primary-Gris-fonc, #929bae);
  font-family: "General Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 160%; /* Approximately 25.6px */
}
.previous-btn-responsive {
  color: #6c4fe0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
v
```

the above template open a dialog which render steper using dynamic components and props
each steper has validation field on click next it checks for validation

```
import { mount  } from "@vue/test-utils";
import OHFeedbackDialog from "@/components/office_hour/OHFeedbackDialog.vue";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import i18n from "@/plugins/i18n";



jest.mock("@/components/base/BaseFeedbackDialog.vue", () => ({
  props: ["setDialogData"],
}));

// Mock the Pinia store
jest.mock("@/store/UiStore", () => {
  return {
    useUiStore: jest.fn(() => ({
      isMobileViewEnabled: false,
    })),
  };
});

jest.mock("@/store/OfficeHoursStore", () => {
  return {
    useOfficeHoursStore: jest.fn(() => ({
      getSubmitFeedback: false,
    })),
  };
});

// Mock the inject function
jest.mock("vue", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("vue"),
  inject: jest.fn((key) => {
    if (key === "clockKey") {
      return {
        parse: jest.fn(() => ({
          toDateComplete: jest.fn(() => "mocked date"),
          toTime: jest.fn(() => "mocked time"),
        })),
      };
    }
  }),
}));

jest.mock("@/assets/default_profile.jpg", () => "mocked-image-path");

describe("OHFeedbackDialog.vue", () => {
  let store: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Create a Pinia store instance for each test
    store = createPinia();
  });

  const mockSetDialogData = {
    id: "7bb6a2c7-ae60-47ea-a7cc-affb8b187c7c",
    program: "Mock Program",
    start_hour: "2023-05-02T02:00:00.000000+0000",
    end_hour: "2023-05-02T03:00:00.000000+0000",
    location: "Mock Location",
    status: "Mock Status",
    expert_id: "aec74887-f43c-4951-a099-8c0a7b526fb2",
    expert_photo: "mock-link",
    expert_job: "Mock job",
    expert_name: "Mock name",
    incubee_id: "Mock id",
    incubee_photo: "mock photo",
    incubee_name: "Mock name",
    program_name: "Mock program",
    purpose: "Mock purpose",
  };
  it("renders correctly when submitFeedback is false", async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(OHFeedbackDialog, {
      props: {
        openDialog: true,
        setDialogData: mockSetDialogData,
      },
      global: {
        plugins: [store,i18n],
      },
    });

    // Wait for Vue to update the DOM
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
  });

  it("renders 'Give Feedback' button when submitFeedback is false", async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(OHFeedbackDialog, {
      props: {
        openDialog: true,
        setDialogData: mockSetDialogData,
      },
      global: {
        plugins: [store,i18n],
        mocks: {
          $t: (msg:any) => msg
        }
      },
    });

    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    // Assert that the 'Give Feedback' button is rendered
    expect(wrapper.find(".bg-primary").text()).toBe("Give Feedback");
  });
});
```

in above test case i have mocked the data for dialog and setup pinia store but getting issue realted to i18n

above is the file of component and testcase ,getting the following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD8Rf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyEzL.png)

I tried multiple online solution already available to mock i18n none of it worked.